# Two google analytics accounts

Tags: merge, google-analytics, accounts

Here is the problem. I added a new analytics code to a page without knowing it already had one.

So now, there are two tracking code in one website, but the report data is different between.

Stupid me .. Now I even do not know which one is correct.

Ideally I want to use all the correct data from both and merge them into one. Probably that is not possible..

Anyone know what should I do?

Thanks for help!

Here is the code.

```
    

      var _gaq = _gaq || [];
      _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'MYSITE_ID_1']);
      _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

      (function() {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
      })();

    


    

      var _gaq = _gaq || [];
      _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'MYSITE_ID_2']);
      _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'mysite.com']);
      _gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);
      _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

      (function() {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async =     true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + 'stats.g.doubleclick.net/dc.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
      })();
```

Comment: Can you include the analytics code for the page you're referring to?

Comment: Any one know about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cant merge data from one account into another. You are probably best off by deciding what account has the best data and then deleting the code for the other from your site. You dont need to close the other account so the data will not be lost. It will just be a pain to pull the data from 2 sources if you need to look into the older data on the other account.

Comment: Thank you. But why the reports are different? Is that because the this two line?  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'mysite.com']);
      _gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);

Comment: The _setAllowLinker code is used to allow the google analytics cookies to pass visitor information from one domain to another. However because you have this code with another code on the same page, this code may be incorrectly installed. All you need is the first code. Do make sure to include the UA of the profile that has the best data though.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the pageview counts are identical in both views, but the visit count is higher in the MYSITE_ID_1 view because it's configured to create a new visitor ID when someone crosses subdomains.

If your web properties share a common domain (e.g. website.com) but you have multiple subdomains (e.g. landing.domain.com and store.domain.com), the MYSITE_ID_2 data is most likely to be correct because it maintains session info across each subdomain.